# Mockito - Unmocked method failed to return the object itself

Tags: java, mockito, this

I have a Spring `@RestController` that has a field of Apache Camel interface `FluentProducerTemplate`.

I am testing the controller with `MockMvc` and I am injecting `FluentProducerTemplate` as a mock.

I would like to mock only one method - `request()`, and use the real implementation of the other methods.

However, I get `NullPointerException` from the unmocked methods. Other `FluentProducerTemplate` methods n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               , their return type is `FluentProducerTemplate`. In the implementation they return `this`. The mock object returns null.

1. I thought that mockito `@Mock` mocks only the methods that I specify. Other methods use the original implementation. Is this a correct statement?
2. I tried `@Spy` instead of `@Mock` and I got the same error.
3. When I mock all the methods that I work with then it works and no `NullPointerException`.

**Code:**

**REST Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/test”)

public class MyController {


@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:main")
private FluentProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

@RequestMapping(value = “/test2”, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public MyResponse testRequest(
        @RequestHeader(“id”) String id,
        @RequestHeader(“context”) String context,
        @RequestBody RequestBody requestBody
) {
    MyResponse response = producerTemplate
            .withHeader(“id”, id)
            .withHeader(“context”, context)
            .withBody(requestBody)
            .request(MyResponse.class);
    return response;
}
```

**Test:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private FluentProducerTemplate producerTemplateMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyControllerTest myController;

    private static MyResponse expectedResultSuccess;

    private static String requestString;

    private static HttpHeaders allRequestHeaders;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {

        allRequestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        allRequestHeaders.set(“id”, “123”);
        allRequestHeaders.set(“context”, “ABCD1234”);
        allRequestHeaders.set(“Content-Type”, “application/json”);

        expectedResultSuccess =  new MyResponse(“test”);

        requestString = “request”BodyText;

    }

    @Before
    public void init() {

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();

        when(producerTemplateMock.request(any())).thenReturn(expectedResultSuccess);

    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccess() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(post(“/v1/test/test2)
                .headers(allRequestHeaders)
                .content(requestString))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())

    }

}
```

The test pass only when I add the below to `init()`:

```
  when(producerTemplateMock.withHeader(any(), any())).thenReturn(producerTemplateMock);
  when(producerTemplateMock.withBody(any())).thenReturn(producerTemplateMock);
```

My main question is - why do I have to mock all methods? 
I prefer to use the original implementation of `withHeader()` and `withBody()` and mock only `request()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want so called partial mocks. Depending on whether you want to set up mostly mocks or mostly call real implementations there are different prefered approaches.

## 1. `spy` for few mocks, mostly real implementation

If you want to mock only some methods and otherwise call the real implementation:

```
FluentProducerTemplate producerTemplateMock = spy(FluentProducerTemplate.class);

// Mock implementation
doReturn(expectedResultSuccess).when(producerTemplateMock).request(any());

// All other method call will use the real implementations
```

## 2. `mock` for mostly mocks, few real implementations

```
FluentProducerTemplate producerTemplateMock = mock(FluentProducerTemplate.class);

// Mock methods
when(producerTemplateMock.request(any())).thenReturn(expectedResultSuccess);

// tell mockito to call the real methods
when(producerTemplateMock.withHeader(any(), any())).thenCallRealMethod;
when(producerTemplateMock.withBody(any())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

As you can see, the 2nd approach is more boilerplate to write. However, it depends on your use case what approach is better suited.

Comment: 1st approach throws `NullPointerExecption`. 
2nd approach - I get this error: `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot call abstract real method on java object!
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking non abstract method.
  //correct example:
  when(mockOfConcreteClass.nonAbstractMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();`
In addition, there are missing brackets in the 2nd option `thenCallRealMethod`.

Comment: 1) what is the stack trace of that Nullpointer Exception? 2) Yes, if the method you are trying to use `thenCallRealMethod` on is `abstract` then there is no implementation available, hence you see the error. Either provide a default implementation or just mock it in the test.

Comment: 1) the mock was not injected so I got the `NullPointerException` from the first `withHeader` call. I tried to use @Spy instead. Then I got `NullPointerException` again, but from the second `withHeader` call. Meaning the mock returned null and didn't perform the real method.

Comment: 2) I noted in my question that FluentProducerTemplate is an Interface. You say that I must mock all the methods in this case? I will try to mock the implementation of the interface and see if Spring know how to inject it to the controller using `@InjectMocks`

Comment: Spring failed to inject the mock if I mock the implementing class and not the interface. I will mock all the methods. Thanks.

Comment: How to inject mocks in a bean using `@InjectMocks` and how to use implementations as mock for interfaces are different questions. But you probably will find solutions to it in the docs or on the internet. :)